# Select nested field in a query with Parse platform

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have extended `Parse.Object` and my subclass has a nested field like this:

```
{
    timesheet: {
        activities: [],
        entries: [],
        clients: []
    }
}
```

`timesheet` can be quite big, so I want to select only a specific field of it:

```
new Parse.Query('MyObject')
    .select('timesheet.activities')
    .find();
```

However, what is returned are all fields of the nested object `timesheet`, not only `activities`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You refactor your code like this :

```
MyObject['timesheet'].activities
```

in this way you can access your object nested property

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not the problem. The problem is I try to `select` only the field "activities" to reduce the response's size. What I get is the entire nested object `timesheet`, when I only want `timesheet.activities`.

Comment: so i think it is much better to handle it in back-end

Comment: I don't want to write a custom cloud function for this. I simply want to know if there's a way for a Parse.Query to select only fields of nested objects.